# Copying all Excel Files in a Folder

Tags: c#, excel, vba

The Issue: 
There are multiple .xls files sent by users to a folder. 
The dataprocessing app we use is not able to read it properly.
But when we open the excel sheet and save it back it works.
So we decided to write a program to do that automatically.

The VB script written was basically opening the excel file, creating a new empty file and copying each sheet to the new file. The problem we faced was "the compatibility prompt" from Office will always popup while saving the new file.

I am trying to create a C# Windows form application, which will do the same. I have gone through a lot of posts in stackoverflow which pertain to this issue but i am not able to make it work. Currently the code i was testing is

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass app = new ApplicationClass();
Workbook curWorkBook = null;
Workbook destWorkbook = null;
Worksheet workSheet = null;
Worksheet newWorksheet = null;
Object defaultArg = Type.Missing;
try
{
     Copy the source sheet
    curWorkBook = app.Workbooks.Open("d:\\oldexcel.xls", defaultArg, defaultArg, defaultArg, defaultArg, defaultArg, defaultArg, defaultArg, defaultArg, defaultArg, defaultArg, defaultArg, defaultArg, defaultArg, defaultArg);
    workSheet = (Worksheet)curWorkBook.Sheets[1];
    workSheet.UsedRange.Copy(defaultArg);

     Paste on destination sheet
    destWorkbook = app.Workbooks.Open("d:\\oldexcel2.xls", defaultArg, false, defaultArg, defaultArg, defaultArg, defaultArg, defaultArg, defaultArg, defaultArg, defaultArg, defaultArg, defaultArg, defaultArg, defaultArg);
    newWorksheet = (Worksheet)destWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(defaultArg, defaultArg, defaultArg, defaultArg);
    newWorksheet.UsedRange._PasteSpecial(XlPasteType.xlPasteValues, XlPasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, false, false);
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
}
finally
{
    if (curWorkBook != null)
    {
        curWorkBook.Save();
        curWorkBook.Close(defaultArg, defaultArg, defaultArg);
    }

    if (destWorkbook != null)
    {
        destWorkbook.Save();
        destWorkbook.Close(defaultArg, defaultArg, defaultArg);
    }
}
app.Quit();
```

This does not work at all, and creates an corrupt file.

Below is the VB script i had written.

```
Dim objExcel, objWorkbook, wbSrc
Dim strFileName, strDirectory, extension, Filename, strFileName2
Dim objFSO, objFolder, objFile

strFileName = "C:\Users\ThirteenCoin\Desktop\testcopy\WH performance KPI project plan 20152.xlsx" '--source file
strFileName2 = "C:\Users\ThirteenCoin\Desktop\testcopy\testcopy\WH performance KPI project plan 20152.xlsx" '--tgtfile

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True

Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add()

extension = "xlsx"

strDirectory = "C:\Users\ThirteenCoin\Desktop\testcopy" '--source directory

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strDirectory)

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    If LCase((objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile))) = LCase(extension) Then
        Filename = objFile.Name
        Filename = strDirectory & "\" & Filename
        Set wbSrc = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(Filename)
        wbSrc.Sheets(1).Copy objWorkbook.Sheets(objWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
        wbSrc.Close
    End If
Next

'~~> Close and Cleanup
objWorkbook.SaveAs (strFileName2)
objWorkbook.Close
objExcel.Quit

Set wbSrc = Nothing
Set objWorkbook = Nothing
Set objExcel = Nothing
```

Kindly advice, as to how to avoid the compatibility prompt or if any better solution is present for such an odd requirement.

Thanks